# mysql.connector in python not working showing no module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I am running this code :

```
`import mysql.connector

 mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="12345"
)

print(mydb)`
```

but getting the error: no module named 'mysql'

[image]

I already installed mysql-connector and mysql-connector-python
and getting an error while installing mysql-connector-rf :
[image]

please help me to resolve this.